# Internal Server Error: Accessing data from php class?

Tags: php, class, internal-server-error

I have another problem.

Im getting an internal server error when I try to get data from the following php class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: -Ryuk-
 * Date: 21/11/12
 * Time: 17:08
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
  */
class game
{
    private $_serverStatus = "Online";
    private $_numOnline = "32";
    private $_maxPlayers = "50";
    private $_messageOfTheDay = "Welcome to game!";
    private $_Players = "Falcubar2011;Zacardor;";

public function GetStatus()
{
    return this::$_serverStatus;
}

public function GetNumOnline()
{
    return this::$_numOnline;
}

public function MaxPlayers()
{
    return this::$_maxPlayers;
}

public function GetMOTD()
{
    return this::$_messageOfTheDay;
}

public function GetPlayers()
{
    return this::$_Players;
}

public function GetServiceColour()
{
    if(this::GetStatus() != "Online")
        return "#FF0000";
    else
        return "#008000";
}
}
```

Im trying to call it like this(in index.php) I stripped this down so you don't get all the junk.

```
$mc = new game();

  <div id="Stats">
        <div id=roundedbox>
            <h1>Info</h1>
            <p>
            <p><strong>IP:</strong> play.game.com</p>
            <br>

            <p>Slots: <?php print $mc->GetNumOnline(); ?> / <?php print $mc->MaxPlayers(); ?></p>
            <br>
            <p>Status: <?php print $mc->GetStatus(); ?></p>
            <br>
            <p>MOTD: <?php print $mc->GetMOTD(); ?></p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem im having?

Comment: 500 errors mean _go look in your web server's error_log_. Then make sure error_reporting is cranked up and `display_errors` turned on in development.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Straight away though, I see that you are not closing `?>` before starting the HTML `<div id"stats">`, which results in a PHP syntax error after `new game();`.

Comment: About not closing the ?> I just stripped this out. as I declare the $mc at the start of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax around `this` is completely wrong. Instead of

```
return this::$_serverStatus;
```

You should be using

```
return $this->_serverStatus;
```

Similarly, your internal call to `GetStatus()` should be

```
if ($this->GetStatus() != 'Online') {
    // ...
```

I recommend you start reading here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php